# What's the difference b/w old and new javascript function syntax?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

How are Foo and Bar any different ?

If objects were only functions, why was this new syntax introduced ? (Foo).

```
var Foo = function(arg) {
    this.attr = arg;
};

function Bar (arg)  {
    this.attr = arg;
}


/*
>>> f = new Foo(3)
Object { attr=3}
>>> f.attr
3
>>> b = new Bar(40)
Bar { attr=40}
>>> b.attr
40
*/
```

A fair amount of documentation I'v read proposes the first syntaxe, but the second one seems to work just as well.

Comment: I feel like this has been asked a lot, google a bit...

Comment: [Allow John Resig to clear this up for you](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#9).

Answer (score 0):

The difference come here:

```
console.log(typeof foo); //'function'
function foo() {
}

console.log(typeof bar); //'undefined'
var bar = function () {
}
```

Comment: While that demonstrates an effect of the primary difference, it doesn't explain it at all.

Comment: I think that the example is clear enough and there's not need for further explanation.